# Access to OctoberCMS page in code?

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend, octobercms-viewbag

I have a Static Page in OctoberCMS named General that has a bunch of site-wide settings including phone number and address. Is it possible to access this page in code to read these settings from its ViewBag?

**UPDATE:** a plugin was created with the following, where properties like `twitter_username` for example can now be accessed in templates with `{{ general('twitter_username') }}`:

```
use System\Classes\PluginBase;
use RainLab\Pages\Classes\Page;
use Cms\Classes\Theme;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    private static $generalViewBag = null;

    public function registerMarkupTags()
    {
        return [
            'functions' => [
                'general' => function($var) {
                    if (self::$generalViewBag === null) {
                        self::$generalViewBag = Page::load(Theme::getActiveTheme(), 'general')
                            ->getViewBag();
                    }

                    return self::$generalViewBag->$var;
                },
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

The `twitter_username` form field was added to the General page in the backend using a separate plugin:

```
use System\Classes\PluginBase;
use Event;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Event::listen('backend.form.extendFields', function($widget) {
            if (! $widget->getController() instanceof \RainLab\Pages\Controllers\Index) {
                return;
            }
            if (! $widget->model instanceof \RainLab\Pages\Classes\Page) {
                return;
            }

            switch ($widget->model->fileName) {
                case 'general.htm':
                    $widget->addFields([
                        'viewBag[twitter_username]' => [
                            'label' => 'Twitter username',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'tab' => 'Social Media',
                        ],
                    ], 'primary');
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do it actually you need to use this code in page life-cycle method

> In **page code block** you can use something like this **OR** anywhere else

```
use RainLab\Pages\Classes\Page as StaticPage;

function onStart() {    
    $pageName = 'static-test';
    $staticPage = StaticPage::load($this->controller->getTheme(), $pageName);
    dd($staticPage->viewBag);    
}
```

let me know if it you find any issues